# Primavera P6 - How to add textbox for input

Tags: primavera

I'm really new to primavera.

I have just installed the primavera p6 8.3 suite. I'm running with the webversion on `http://localhost:8203/p6/action/home`, all fine and dandy.

I have the API installed and I understand what I can use it for however, let's says I want to add a textbox for example to show or to take userinput. How would I go about to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Primavera API to perform CRUD operations,integration with other products .
All the operations performed will be donenot done according to privileges of the user you have used to log in the API.
A guide to all exposed functions of API
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16281_01/Technical_Documentation/Integration_API/ProgrammerReference.html

Coming to your question, you can create the UI for this in manner similar to any other java code (swing) and then you can use the API functions to perform operations on DB fetch results and display it in your UI.